# Переключение блоков

Tags: jquery

Всем доброго времени суток, столкнулся с такой проблемой есть блок с классом block2, который открыт и два блока block1,block3, которые скрыты. Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы кликая по + становился аквным следующий блок, а если нажать на -, то активным становился предыдущий?

```
<div classs="left">-</div>
<div class="right">+</div>

<br>
<div class="block1">1</div>
<div class="block2">2</div>
<div class="block3">3</div>
<br>
<div class="block1">1</div>
<div class="block2">2</div>
<div class="block3">3</div>

.right {
  height: 10px;  
  width: 10px;
}
.left {
  height: 10px; 
  width: 10px;
}
.block1,.block3 {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0):

например:

```js
$('.left').on('click', function(){
  var
    item = $('.block2'),
    prev = item.prev(),
    next = item.next();
  
  prev.show();
  next.hide();
     
});

$('.right').on('click', function(){
  var
    item = $('.block2'),
    prev = item.prev(),
    next = item.next();
  
  next.show();
  prev.hide();
     
});
```

```css
.right,
.left {
  height: 10px;  
  width: 10px;
}

.block1,.block3 {
  display: none;
}

/* Доп.стилизация для наглядности */
.right,
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
  
<div class="left">-</div>
<div class="right">+</div>

<br>
<div class="block1">1</div>
<div class="block2">2</div>
<div class="block3">3</div>
<br>
<div class="block1">1</div>
<div class="block2">2</div>
<div class="block3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click",".right",function(){
    var idx;
    var len=$(".colum_hidden")
    $(".colum_hidden").each(function(i,e){
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            idx=i;
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
    }) 
    idx++
    idx=(idx==3)?idx=0:idx;
    len.eq(idx).addClass("active")
})

$(document).on("click",".left",function(){
    var idx;
    var len=$(".colum_hidden")
    $(".colum_hidden").each(function(i,e){
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            idx=i;
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
    }) 
    idx--;
    console.log(idx)
    idx=(idx==0)?idx=2:idx;
    console.log(idx)
    len.eq(idx).addClass("active")
}) 
<div class="left">-</div>
<div class="right">+</div>

<br>
<div class="colum_hidden">1</div>
<div class="colum_hidden active">2</div>
<div class="colum_hidden">3</div>
```